# Concatenating multiple csv files into a single csv with the same header

Tags: python, csv, pandas, terminal, concatenation

I am currently using the below code to import 6,000 csv files (with headers) and export them into a single csv file (with a single header row).

```
#import csv files from folder
path =r'data/US/market/merged_data'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
stockstats_data = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []

for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None,)
    list_.append(df)
    stockstats_data = pd.concat(list_)
    print(file_ + " has been imported.")
```

This code works fine, but it is slow. It can take up to 2 days to process.

I was given a single line script for Terminal command line that does the same (but with no headers). This script takes 20 seconds.

```
 for f in *.csv; do cat "`pwd`/$f" | tail -n +2 >> merged.csv; done
```

Does anyone know how I can speed up the first Python script? To cut the time down, I have thought about not importing it into a DataFrame and just concatenating the CSVs, but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you don't need the CSV in memory, just copying from input to output, it'll be a lot cheaper to avoid parsing at all, and copy without building up in memory:

```
import shutil
import glob


#import csv files from folder
path = r'data/US/market/merged_data'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
allFiles.sort()  # glob lacks reliable ordering, so impose your own if output order matters
with open('someoutputfile.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
        with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
            if i != 0:
                infile.readline()  # Throw away header on all but first file
            # Block copy rest of file from input to output without parsing
            shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
            print(fname + " has been imported.")
```

That's it; [`shutil.copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) handles efficiently copying the data, dramatically reducing the Python level work to parse and reserialize. Don't omit the `allFiles.sort()`!†

This assumes all the CSV files have the same format, encoding, line endings, etc., the encoding encodes such that newlines appear as a single byte equivalent to ASCII `\n` and it's the last byte in the character (so ASCII and all ASCII superset encodings work, as does UTF-16-BE and UTF-32-BE, but not UTF-16-LE and UTF-32-LE) and the header doesn't contain embedded newlines, but if that's the case, it's a lot faster than the alternatives.

For the cases where the encoding's version of a newline doesn't look enough like an ASCII newline, or where the input files are in one encoding, and the output file should be in a different encoding, you can add the work of encoding and decoding without adding CSV parsing/serializing work, with (adding a `from io import open` if on Python 2, to get Python 3-like efficient encoding-aware file objects, and defining `known_input_encoding` to some string representing the known encoding for input files, e.g. `known_input_encoding = 'utf-16-le'`, and optionally a different encoding for output files):

```
# Other imports and setup code prior to first with unchanged from before

# Perform encoding to chosen output encoding, disabling line-ending 
# translation to avoid conflicting with CSV dialect, matching raw binary behavior
with open('someoutputfile.csv', 'w', encoding=output_encoding, newline='') as outfile:
    for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
        # Decode with known encoding, disabling line-ending translation
        # for same reasons as above
        with open(fname, encoding=known_input_encoding, newline='') as infile:
            if i != 0:
                infile.readline()  # Throw away header on all but first file
            # Block copy rest of file from input to output without parsing
            # just letting the file object decode from input and encode to output
            shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
            print(fname + " has been imported.")
```

This is still *much* faster than involving the `csv` module, especially in modern Python (where the `io` module has undergone greater and greater optimization, to the point where the cost of decoding and reencoding is pretty minor, especially next to the cost of performing I/O in the first place). It's also a good validity check for self-checking encodings (e.g. the UTF family) even if the encoding is not supposed to change; if the data doesn't match the assumed self-checking encoding, it's highly unlikely to decode validly, so you'll get an exception rather than silent misbehavior.

---

Because [some of the duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57651760/364696) linked here are looking for an even faster solution than `copyfileobj`, some options:

1. The only succinct, reasonably portable option is to continue using `copyfileobj` and explicitly pass a non-default `length` parameter, e.g. `shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile, 1 << 20)` (`1 << 20` is 1 MiB, a number which `shutil` has switched to for plain `shutil.copyfile` calls on Windows due to superior performance).
2. Still portable, but only works for binary files and not succinct, would be to copy the underlying code `copyfile` uses on Windows, which uses a reusable `bytearray` buffer with a larger size than `copyfileobj`'s default (1 MiB, rather than 64 KiB), removing some allocation overhead that `copyfileobj` can't fully avoid for large buffers. You'd replace `shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)` with (3.8+'s walrus operator, `:=`, used for brevity) the following code adapted from CPython 3.10's implementation of `shutil._copyfileobj_readinto` (which you could always use directly if you don't mind using non-public APIs):

   ```
   buf_length = 1 << 20  # 1 MiB buffer; tweak to preference
   # Using a memoryview gets zero copy performance when short reads occur
   with memoryview(bytearray(buf_length)) as mv:  
       while n := infile.readinto(mv):
           if n < buf_length:
               with mv[:n] as smv:
                   outfile.write(smv)
           else:
               outfile.write(mv)
   ```
3. Non-portably, if you can (in any way you feel like) determine the precise length of the header, and you know it will not change by even a byte in any other file, you can write the header directly, then use OS-specific calls similar to what `shutil.copyfile` uses under the hood to copy the non-header portion of each file, using OS-specific APIs that can do the work with a single system call (regardless of file size) and avoid extra data copies (by pushing all the work to in-kernel or even within file-system operations, removing copies to and from user space) e.g.:

   a. On Linux kernel 2.6.33 and higher (and any other OS that allows the `sendfile(2)` system call to work between open files), you can replace the `.readline()` and `copyfileobj` calls with:

   ```
   filesize = os.fstat(infile.fileno()).st_size  # Get underlying file's size
   os.sendfile(outfile.fileno(), infile.fileno(), header_len_bytes, filesize - header_len_bytes)
   ```

   To make it signal resilient, it may be necessary to check the return value from `sendfile`, and track the number of bytes sent + skipped and the number remaining, looping until you've copied them all (these are low level system calls, they can be interrupted).

   b. On any system Python 3.8+ built with glibc >= 2.27 (or on Linux kernel 4.5+), where the files are all on the same filesystem, you can replace `sendfile` with `copy_file_range`:

   ```
   filesize = os.fstat(infile.fileno()).st_size  # Get underlying file's size
   os.copy_file_range(infile.fileno(), outfile.fileno(), filesize - header_len_bytes, header_len_bytes)
   ```

   With similar caveats about checking for copying fewer bytes than expected and retrying.

   c. On OSX/macOS, you can use the completely undocumented, and therefore even less portable/stable API `shutil.copyfile` uses, `posix._fcopyfile` for a similar purpose, with something like (completely untested, and really, don't do this; it's likely to break across even minor Python releases):

   ```
   infile.seek(header_len_bytes)  # Skip past header
   posix._fcopyfile(infile.fileno(), outfile.fileno(), posix._COPYFILE_DATA)
   ```

   which assumes `fcopyfile` pays attention to the seek position (docs aren't 100% on this) and, as noted, is not only macOS-specific, but uses undocumented CPython internals that could change in any release.

---

† An aside on sorting the results of `glob`: That `allFiles.sort()` call should not be omitted; `glob` imposes no ordering on the results, and for reproducible results, you'll want to impose *some* ordering (it wouldn't be great if the same files, with the same names and data, produced an output file in a different order simply because in-between runs, a file got moved out of the directory, then back in, and changed the native iteration order).  Without the `sort` call, this code (and all other Python+glob module answers) will not reliably read from a directory containing `a.csv` and `b.csv` in alphabetical (or any other useful) order; it'll vary by OS, file system, and often the entire history of file creation/deletion in the directory in question. This has broken stuff before in the real world, see details at [A Code Glitch May Have Caused Errors In More Than 100 Published Studies](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/zmjwda/a-code-glitch-may-have-caused-errors-in-more-than-100-published-studies).

Answer (score 12):

Are you required to do this in Python? If you are open to doing this entirely in shell, all you'd need to do is first `cat` the header row from a randomly selected input .csv file into `merged.csv` before running your one-liner:

```
cat a-randomly-selected-csv-file.csv | head -n1 > merged.csv
for f in *.csv; do cat "`pwd`/$f" | tail -n +2 >> merged.csv; done
```

Comment: thanks for your help - I do need it in Python as part of a bigger project. Cheers.

Comment: @mattblack, I should have figured that was the case. Hopefully Alexander's answer works for you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need pandas for this, just the simple `csv` module would work fine.

```
import csv

df_out_filename = 'df_out.csv'
write_headers = True
with open(df_out_filename, 'wb') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for filename in allFiles:
        with open(filename) as fin:
            reader = csv.reader(fin)
            headers = reader.next()
            if write_headers:
                write_headers = False  # Only write headers once.
                writer.writerow(headers)
            writer.writerows(reader)  # Write all remaining rows.
```

Comment: A couple issues with this: 1) You opened the input files in text mode, the output in binary, which wouldn't work at all on Py3, and it's wrong on a Windows box even on Py2 (where you'd convert `\r\n` line endings in the inputs to `\n` line endings in the output). Sadly, it's not possible to make it fully portable without a lot of effort or third party modules (because the `csv` module requires binary I/O on Py2, and text I/O with `newline=''` on Py3). 2) (Minor) If nothing else, `headers = reader.next()` could be changed to `headers = next(reader)` to make it work on 2.6-3.x, not just 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler approach - you can use pandas (though I am not sure how it will help with RAM usage)-

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

path =r'data/US/market/merged_data'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
stockstats_data = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []

for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_)
    stockstats_data = pd.concat((df, stockstats_data), axis=0)
```