# concatenate all files into a directory with python

Tags: python, concatenation

I actually have to cat all files into a directory but with python.
In bash command it would be:

```
cat ./* > newfile
```

I guess it should be something like that:

```
with open(new_directory_0035+"/merged.txt", 'w') as f:
    for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob(new_directory_0035+"/*")):
        f.write(line)
    fileinput.close()
```

but it is still running after 20 minutes, do you know if I wrote something wrong?
And it seems to take to much memory as well...
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-to-merge-200-csv-files-in-python) | [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791212/concatenating-multiple-csv-files-into-a-single-csv-with-the-same-header-python) | [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335474/merging-multiple-csv-files-without-headers-being-repeated-using-python)?

Comment: Hi, well these exemples are for dataframe, but me if for fasta files to creat one unique multiple fasta file not merge several dataframe in csv format