# shutil.copyfileobj but without headers or skip first line

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, shutil

I have about 8000 `text` files which contain csv data like

```
CustomerID,Gender,Day,SaleAmount
18,Male,Monday,71.55
24,Female,Monday,219.66
112,Male,Friday,150.44
```

My code is looping through all the files and then appending it to `final.txt`-

```
with open('final.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    for filename in files:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as readfile:
            shutil.copyfileobj(readfile, outfile)
```

Now the problem is since each file has it's own header i.e.

```
+------------+--------+-----+------------+
| CustomerID | Gender | Day | SaleAmount |
+------------+--------+-----+------------+
```

My final content looks like this -

```
+------------+--------+--------+------------+
| CustomerID | Gender |  Day   | SaleAmount |
+------------+--------+--------+------------+
| 18         | Male   | Monday | 71.55      |
| 24         | Female | Monday | 219.66     |
| 112        | Male   | Friday | 150.44     |
| CustomerID | Gender | Day    | SaleAmount |
| 28         | Male   | Monday | 7.55       |
| 34         | Female | Monday | 19.66      |
| 12         | Female | Friday | 150.44     |
| CustomerID | Gender | Day    | SaleAmount |
| 28         | Male   | Monday | 7.55       |
| 34         | Female | Monday | 19.66      |
| 12         | Female | Friday | 150.44     |
+------------+--------+--------+------------+
```

Is there a way to merge all the 8000 txt files into one keeping just one header using shutil.copyfileobj?

I've tried using pd.read_csv but copyfileobj is twice as fast. Are there any other faster way to do this?

EDIT - I am reading directly from txt files and not dataframes.

Comment: FYI, I've updated [my answer on the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44791486/364696) to address various ways of beating the speed of a plain `shutil.copyfileobj` call. Practically speaking, I'm going to recommend sticking to `shutil.copyfileobj`, for succinctness and good enough performance; unless your input files are huge, the optimizations aren't going to save much (the optimizations just reduce the number of system calls and the amount of data copied from kernel to user mode and back, but that'll be meaningless next to the fixed per-file syscalls when the files are smallish).